# Textarea isn't rendering in IE7

Tags: javascript, forms, internet-explorer-7, rendering, textarea

For some reason my textareas are not being show in IE7. I am using checkboxes in a form, and when they clicked, it called a javascript function that opens up a corresponding textarea. It works fine in every other main browser but not in IE7.

Here is an example of the code I'm using.

The HTML:

```
<input name="areasOfConcern1" type="checkbox" id="concern1" value="Frequently misses classes" onClick="checkedTest('concern1', 'concern1Text')" onblur="checkedTest('concern1', 'concern1Text')" />
 Attendance
 <div id="concern1Text" style="visibility:hidden;position:absolute;display:none;">
 <textarea  onfocus="removeText(this)" onblur="addText(this)" cols="90" name="areasOfConcern1Text" id="areasOfConcern1Text">Comments...</textarea>
</div>
```

The JS Function:

```
function checkedTest(checkBox, divId)
{
 box = eval("document.getElementById(checkBox)");
 div = eval("document.getElementById(divId)");
 if(box.checked == true)
 {
  div.style.visibility="visible";
  div.style.display="block";
  div.style.position="relative";
 }
 else
 {
  div.style.visibility="hidden";
  div.style.display="none";
  div.style.position="absolute";
 }
}
```

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: ...and totally unnecessary in this case.

Comment: ..... true ;) this only is more work to type in, programmers aren't lazy, they like to work as effective and efficient as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that visibilty and display, or maybe your position are the problem? I don't spot any problem in the code after reading a few times. When I want to toggle elements I only use the `display` attribute and this works fine for me, also in IE.

Answer (score 1):

the problem seems to be due to setting `div.style.position`, although I'm not sure why it is. Removing the `position` style from `concern1Text` and removing the related js assignment statemnts seems to fix the issue.

and as long as we're fixing things, the first 2 lines of your method should not be using `eval`. they can be written in the form of

```
box = document.getElementById(checkBox);
```